# PC Not Booting After ACER Logo

Tags: boot, virtualbox, acer-aspire

My ACER Aspire E5-521-238Q running Windows 10 Build 9926 won't boot. I see the ACER: EXPLORE BEYOND LIMITS and the loading thing and then the PC is on, but has a black screen. When I press Alt + F10 it's supposed to bring me to the recovery menu, but says "Windows did not start correctly" and gives me the option to go to the recovery menu. It happened when I installed VirtualBox and it was taking forever while installing the Networking Features. So I pressed Cancel and it didn't cancel so I closed it with Task Manager and restarted my PC. That's when the problems started happening. Could it might have uninstalled the networking drivers? A reply would be very much appreciated as I am a 9 year old and I got my laptop last Christmas and I really want it to start working again. No, I am not the 9 year old's dad typing, I really do know all this stuff...

Comment: Does it boot from a USB drive? If yes then I recommend going back to a stable OS like Win7 or 8.1.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195939/minimum-age-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @Karan Or I could reinstall Win10 from a USB and try again?

Comment: I would download and install a new build from here ==> http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-iso

Comment: @whs Can you get older builds, because the only build I can download is the one I had originally.

Comment: @JasonAller You can be on Stack Exchange under 13 as long as you don't give away any personal info.

Comment: @GabrielCollins: Yeah, you could if you feel confident continuing with the experiment knowing you might end up in such situations again given the state of the OS right now.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand. Why exactly could you not download the current build.